# Bitnami Wordpress with Google Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, bitnami, google-cloud-load-balancer

My setup is Bitnami WordPress and Google Cloud Load Balancer. I've encountered a few issues.

To use a load balancer with Bitnami WordPress, I've to use this

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

That allows the VM to be accessible by both IP and domain. The problem is Google is indexing the VM's IP and some plugins are using the VM's IP too.

Neither can I use `HTTPS` because the SSL is handled by the Load Balancer. That causes mixed content issues on some pages when some plugins are used. Adding X-Forwarded-Proto doesn't work.

The website will break if I use any other configuration other than

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

I wonder if it is because of my configuration error or is the native behaviour of Bitnami WordPress.

Comment: `X-Forwarded-Proto` is the correct method. Saying it does not work is not a good problem description. Clearly define what you configured and what does not work.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. Saying `X-Forwarded-Proto` does not work mean adding that does not make any changes to the website. In the post, `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');` is the configuration.

Comment: I do not see that configuration in your question. Also, are you redirecting users from HTTP to HTTPS? There are three areas with WordPress. 1) `x-forwarded-proto`. 2) HTTPS redirection. 3) Correct URLs in the content.

Comment: @JohnHanley It is a default Bitnami WordPress set up. HTTP to HTTPS redirection is handed by load balancer.

Comment: Comments like that are not productive. How did you verify that WordPress is correctly handling HTTP versus HTTPS?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not sure which part of the post is not clear. The problem is Bitnami WordPress does not correctly handle HTTP to HTTPS redirection when a load balancer is used. Bitnami WordPress has a different setup than the default WordPress.

Comment: You are responsible for posting the details required to answer or solve your problem. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley I don't think I have more info to add. Bitnami Wordpress has a different setup than normal WordPress. It is the default configuration of Bitnami WordPress and the main problem is it doesn't recognize Google Load Balancer to handle HTTPS redirection.